# Printing the digits of a number in reverse order

Tags: java, number-formatting

Can someone please help me solve this? The number should be variable and not constant.
The output should be:

```
Timestamping In 6 Digit
8
5
6
3
0
1
Average In 6 Digit
9
8
7
6
5
2
```

```
class Timestamp1 extends Average1
{
  public static void main (String args[]) {

    int i = 103658;
    int j = 10;
    int k = i % j;
    System.out.println(" Timestamping In 6 Digit " );
    System.out.println(" " + k);

    int o = 10365;
    int p = 10;
    int q = o % p;
    System.out.println(" " + q);

    int l = 1036;
    int m = 10;
    int n = l % m;
    System.out.println(" " + n);

    int r = 103;
    int s = 10;
    int t = r % s;
    System.out.println(" " + t);

    int u = 10;
    int v = 10;
    int w = u % v;
    System.out.println(" " + w);

    int x = 1;
    int y = 10;
    int z = x % y;
    System.out.println(" " + z);




class Average1 extends Timestamp1 {

  public void main() {

    int i = 256789;
    int j = 10;
    int k = i % j;
    System.out.println(" Average In 6 Digit ");
    System.out.println(" " + k);

    int o = 25678;
    int p = 10;
    int q = o % p;
    System.out.println(" " + q);

    int l = 2567;
    int m = 10;
    int n = l % m;
    System.out.println(" " + n);

    int r = 256;
    int s = 10;
    int t = r % s;
    System.out.println(" " + t);

    int u = 25;
    int v = 10;
    int w = u % v;
    System.out.println(" " + w);

    int x = 2;
    int y = 10;
    int z = x % y;
    System.out.println(" " + z);
  }


}
}
}
```

Comment: To help us understand your problem, please tell us more about it. What happens before, what do the numbers mean, and why do you need them in digits and reversed?

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to reverse a number then here you go

```
public String reverseNum(Integer i)
{
return new StringBuilder(i.toString()).reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you really want to do? Print two integer numbers reversed? Then you should say so.

```
public static String reverseDigits(int i) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(i);
  sb.reverse();
  return sb.toString();
}

...
System.out.println(reverseDigits(1234567));
...
```

Comment: or you can use the reverse() method inbuilt with StringBuilder ;-)