# Multiplying f timestamp and average

Tags: java

Here is the coding for timestamp and average of pixel. how to multiply timestamp value and average value??

**Coding for timestamp:**

```
public class GetTimeStamp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println(new java.sql.Time(time.getTime()));
  }
}
```

**Coding For Avarage:**

```
class Average1 {

public static void main (String args[]){

    int one = 256789;
    int two = 10;
    int three = one % two;
    System.out.println(" Average In 6 Digit ");
    System.out.println(" " + three);

    int four = 25678;
    int five = 10;
    int six = four % five;
    System.out.println(" " + six);

    int seven = 2567;
    int eight = 10;
    int nine = seven % eight;
    System.out.println(" " + nine);

    int ten = 256;
    int eleven = 10;
    int twelve = ten % eleven;
    System.out.println(" " + twelve);

    int a = 25;
    int b = 10;
    int c = a % b;
    System.out.println(" " + c);

    int d = 2;
    int e = 10;
    int f = d % e;
    System.out.println(" " + f);
  }


}
```

Comment: why I have this feeling that I have seen this question before. Is it homework question and your classmates are also asking this on SO. Sorry, if I am wrong. But as I said I have this feeling. :)

Comment: what is your question ? .getTime() * average value ?

Comment: maybe he want's an algorithm for multiplication and average of timestamp digits (i hope i sound better)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533494

Comment: Was your question answered sufficiently?

Answer (score 0):

In your "code for average" example you are using `%` which is modulus where you need to use `/` which is division.

```
int first = 30;
int second = 10;
int average = first / second;;
System.out.println( average );
```

Other than that I don't understand what you are asking.