# Which of recursion method is better and why for reverse digits of integer?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static int recursiveReverse(int number, int reversenumber){

    if(number <= 0) {
        return reversenumber;
    }

    reversenumber = reversenumber * 10 + (number % 10);
    number = number/10;

    return recursiveReverse(number, reversenumber);
}
```

OR

```
private static int reversenumber = 0;

public static int recursiveReverse(int number){

    if(number <= 0) {
        return reversenumber;
    }

    reversenumber = reversenumber * 10 + (number % 10);
    number = number / 10;

    return recursiveReverse(number);  
}
```

Comment: If you reverse `200` it becomes `2` I assume this is homework because I would use a String and not use recursion.

Comment: Shouldn't you cast the number as a string before you treat it like a string?

Comment: @Peter: What would you think it should be?

Comment: @Nilesh Salpe, the first two are identical...

Comment: @Dan Tao. I would do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533494/printing-the-digits-of-a-number-in-reverse-order

Comment: @Bart, the first one has an extra space. ;)

Comment: 2nd one is best. It's bad style to put a space before a comma in an argument definition, and using static variables to keep track of state is worse.

Comment: @Peter: OK, but he said reverse the digits of a *number*, not the *textual representation of a number*. I will grant you this is ambiguous (and "reversing the digits" seems very text-like and not number-like), but I wouldn't assume the OP wants a `String` out, if he declared a return type of `int`. (He'll have to clarify.)

Comment: @Dan Tao, If you reverse something twice it should go back the way it was, but `200` will become `2` which becomes `2`. `-1` becomes `0` ;)

Comment: @Peter: I don't know, that sounds to me like your own assumption that you've added as a requirement. The OP may have no interest in reversing back to the original. Again, he'd have to clarify.

Comment: Dude admin has changed my code :(

Answer (score 5):

Definitely **not** the last one. Putting a state-holding variable in a static field is just asking for trouble. Not that you're necessarily designing for concurrency, but if you had multiple threads running this code, for example, the shared `reverseNumber` field would totally wreck everything.

I don't see any difference between the first and second. (Literally, they appear identical to me.)

If your goal is to simplify the calling convention by having a default value for the second parameter (`reverseNumber`), then simply overload your method:

```
public static int recursiveReverse(int number) {
    return recursiveReverse(number, 0);
}

private static int recursiveReverse(int number, int reverseNumber) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: You're clearly blind. The first one has `int number , int reversenumber`, whereas the second only has `int number, int reversenumber`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any difference between the first and second example

but using a static variable in the third example is dangerous (you need to reset it each time and it's not threadsafe)

Answer (score 2):

I think condition (n <= 0) adds extra 0 in the end. Comparing with 10 (n <= 10) returns correctly reversed integer

```
public int rev(int n){
    if(n <= 10) {
        return n;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt("" + (n % 10) + rev(n / 10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with the following:

```
public int rev(int n){
    if(n <= 0) {
        return n;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt("" + (n % 10) + rev(n / 10));
}
```

This way you don't need a temporary variable to hold state and it satisfies the return type.
Hope this helps!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very shortest/simplest way in two lines code:

```
public static int reverseNumber(int n) 
{
    System.out.println(n % 10);
    return (n/10 > 0) ? reverseNumber(n/10) : n;
}
```